# Twitter API using Tweepy. Basic Error: <bound method API.me of <tweepy.api.API object at 0x7f0116b9f1d0>>

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I am following a tutorial and using for the first time the Twitter API, I have the following code (obviously not secret):

```
import tweepy
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('SECRET','SECRET')
auth.set_access_token('import tweepy
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('xoPKlx38YYsVDXmkS7zkDiVqz','RKDv8OwSzrvp1L41n6cMxXDAquU74fccIqobqcCwRpEf4SiYVg')
auth.set_access_token('2869424045-Ch8L9tlUd9qXaoXzAD4Db0OIIYzVP8b1cOoE0Ow','1C9wPDHZnvStmzYuoRhAUpmOEz4tZZCsLY7TTY8wYzOAZ')

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

user = api.me

print(user.screen_name)','SECRET')

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

user = api.me

print(user)
```

I am receiving the error `<bound method API.me of <tweepy.api.API object at 0x7f0116b9f1d0>>`

I am also curious why only works when I type Python3 and not Python just before the name of the .py

Comment: Possibly because `python` is using Python 2 while `python3` uses some version of Python 3.x (as you would expect from the latter command), and something in your script or the library you're using is incompatible with Python 2. What version numbers do you get when you run `python --version` and `python3 --version`?

Comment: I get Python 3.6.9